# Extracting Information from the Decision Rules in rpart package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I need to extract information from the rules in decision tree. I am using rpart package in R. I am using demo data in the package to explain my requirements:

```
data(stagec)
fit<- rpart(formula = pgstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + ploidy, data = stagec, method = "class", control=rpart.control(cp=0.05))
fit
```

printing fit shows

```
n= 146 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 146 54 0 (0.6301370 0.3698630)  
   2) grade< 2.5 61  9 0 (0.8524590 0.1475410) *
   3) grade>=2.5 85 40 1 (0.4705882 0.5294118)  
     6) g2< 13.2 40 17 0 (0.5750000 0.4250000)  
      12) ploidy=diploid,tetraploid 31 11 0 (0.6451613 0.3548387) *
      13) ploidy=aneuploid 9  3 1 (0.3333333 0.6666667) *
     7) g2>=13.2 45 17 1 (0.3777778 0.6222222)  
      14) g2>=17.91 22  8 0 (0.6363636 0.3636364) *
      15) g2< 17.91 23  3 1 (0.1304348 0.8695652) *
```

e.g. I would like to get  information something like below for the 12th node

If grade>=2.5 and g2< 13.2 and ploidy in (diploid,tetraploid) then class 0 is predicted with 65% confidence. Any pointers on this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use [`list.rules.rpart()`](http://www.togaware.com/datamining/survivor/Convert_Tree.html) as a basis: `library(rpart);fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis);list.rules.rpart(fit)`.

Answer (score 7):

The
[rpart.plot](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rpart.plot)
package version 3.0 (July 2018) has a function
`rpart.rules` for generating a set of rules for a tree. For example

```
library(rpart.plot)
data(stagec)
fit <- rpart(formula = pgstat ~ ., data = stagec, method = "class", control=rpart.control(cp=0.05))
rpart.rules(fit)
```

gives

```
pgstat                                                                   
  0.15 when grade <  3                                                   
  0.35 when grade >= 3 & g2 <  13       & ploidy is diploid or tetraploid
  0.36 when grade >= 3 & g2 >=       18                                  
  0.67 when grade >= 3 & g2 <  13       & ploidy is             aneuploid
  0.87 when grade >= 3 & g2 is 13 to 18
```

And

```
rpart.rules(fit, roundint=FALSE, clip.facs=TRUE)
```

gives

```
pgstat                                                           
  0.15 when grade <  2.5                                         
  0.35 when grade >= 2.5 & g2 <  13       & diploid or tetraploid
  0.36 when grade >= 2.5 & g2 >=       18                        
  0.67 when grade >= 2.5 & g2 <  13       & aneuploid
  0.87 when grade >= 2.5 & g2 is 13 to 18
```

For more examples see Chapter 4 of the
[rpart.plot vignette](http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf).

Comment: I keep receiving the following error: `Error in rpart.rules(fit) : could not find function "rpart.rules"`. Do you know why?

Comment: My fit is valid (at least judging by my ability to plot it and add a text overlay)

Comment: When I restart my R session, load `rpart` and check for the contained methods, `rpart.rules` is not listed.

Comment: Note that `rpart.rules` is part of the the `rpart.plot` package (not the `rpart `package), so make sure you use `library(rpart.plot)` before invoking `rpart.rules`.  Also make sure you are using `rpart.plot` package version 3.0.0 or higher.

Comment: @StephenMilborrow : can you please take a look at my question if you have time ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function (note: the computer I am using does not have internet access or a usb port, I only have R with a few preinstalled libraries. I have "rpart" but I unable to install the "rpart.plot" library. Therefore, I am looking for a way to obtain decision rules only using rpart, base R, party and partykit. I consulted the answer below yours on this same stackoverflow page, it works - but I am unable to get the full rules. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `list.rules.party()` function from the [partykit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/index.html) package and a little bit of string formatting. Here is an example using your code.

```
data(stagec)
fit <- rpart(
  formula = pgstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + ploidy,
  data = stagec,
  method = "class",
  control = rpart.control(cp = 0.05)
)

party_obj <- as.party.rpart(fit, data = TRUE)
decisions <- partykit:::.list.rules.party(party_obj)
cat(paste(decisions, collapse = "\n"))
```

As you can see, you build your tree model the same way. Then you transform your model into a party object and use the `list.rules.party()` function to extract the decision strings. A little bit of formatting and you get

```
grade < 2.5
grade >= 2.5 & g2 < 13.2 & ploidy %in% c("diploid", "tetraploid")
grade >= 2.5 & g2 < 13.2 & ploidy %in% c("aneuploid")
grade >= 2.5 & g2 >= 13.2 & g2 >= 17.91
grade >= 2.5 & g2 >= 13.2 & g2 < 17.91
```

as the result.

Comment: Great answer! I just tried this on my data and it worked. I just had a question : when I tried my code (over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function)  .... "cat(paste(decisions, collapse = "\n"))" this line will not tell me which class of the response variable that row will result in. If you have time, can you please take a look at it? Thanks!