# R: Extracting Rules from a Decision Tree

Tags: r, tree, data-manipulation, prediction, decision-tree

I am working with the R programming language. Recently, I read about a new decision tree algorithm called "Reinforcement Learning Trees" (RLT)  which supposedly has the potential to fit "better" decision trees to a dataset. The documentation for this library is available over here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RLT/RLT.pdf

I tried to use this library to run a classification decision tree on the (famous) Iris Dataset:

```
library(RLT)
data(iris)
fit = RLT(iris[,c(1,2,3,4)], iris$Species, model = "classification", ntrees = 1)
```

**Question:** From here, is it possible to extract the "rules" from this decision tree?

For example, if you use the CART Decision Tree model:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

fit <-rpart( Species ~. , data = iris)
rpart.plot(fit)
```

[image]

```
 rpart.rules(fit)

    Species  seto vers virg                                               
     setosa [1.00  .00  .00] when Petal.Length <  2.5                     
 versicolor [ .00  .91  .09] when Petal.Length >= 2.5 & Petal.Width <  1.8
  virginica [ .00  .02  .98] when Petal.Length >= 2.5 & Petal.Width >= 1.8
```

Is it possible to do this with the RLT library? I have been reading the documentation for this library and can not seem to find a direct way to extract the decision rules. I understand that this library is typically meant to be used as a substitute for the random forest (which do not have decision rules) - but I was reading the original paper for this algorithm where they specify that the RLT algorithm fit individual decision trees (via the RLT algorithm) and then aggregates them together as in random forest. Thus on some level, the RLT algorithm is able to fit an individual decision tree - which in theory should have "decision rules".

Does anyone know how to extract these rules?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277625959_Reinforcement_Learning_Trees

Comment: Since [doing it this way isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401411/extracting-information-from-the-decision-rules-in-rpart-package?rq=1), have you looked at the [tests](https://github.com/teazrq/RLT) that might provide a door to entry, but it seems, considering [what probability refers to which var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function), that resort to understanding [supplementary materials - pdf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4760114/bin/NIHMS676643-supplement-Supplemental_material.pdf) might come be necessary.

Comment: Tests can be revealing, but I'll say I have to take the supplementary stuff as 'they know what they're saying' and way over my head, but three classes, muted - not stuff we want to split on, strong - find best place to split,  and something else, but perhaps the default tuning parameters (supp. pg 15) are effectively the rules.

Answer (score 12):

The rules are stored in `fit$FittedTrees[[1]]` in a tabular format that is relatively difficult to interpret.

I have constructed a rather long function for you that will extract the rules as a data frame and additionally plot the tree as a ggplot if requested.

```r
RLT_tree <- function(RLT_obj, plot = TRUE)
{
  
  tree <- as.data.frame(t(RLT_obj$FittedTrees[[1]]))
  tree <- tree[c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, grep("Class\\d", names(tree)))]
  class_cols <- grep("Class\\d", names(tree))
  names(tree)[class_cols] <-
    RLT_obj$ylevels[1 + as.numeric(sub("Class(\\d+)", "\\1",
                                   names(tree)[class_cols]))]
  tree$variable <- RLT_obj$variablenames[tree$SplitVar1]
  tree$variable[is.na(tree$variable)] <- "(Leaf node)"
  tree$rule <- tree$variable
  tree$depth <- numeric(nrow(tree))
  tree$rightness <- numeric(nrow(tree))
  tree$group <- character(nrow(tree))
  
  walk_tree <- function(node, depth, rightness, node_label = "Start", group = "S")
  {
    new_row <- tree[which(tree$Node == node),]
    new_row$depth <- depth
    new_row$rightness <- rightness
    left_label <- paste(new_row$variable, new_row$SplitValue, sep = " < ")
    right_label <- paste(new_row$variable, new_row$SplitValue, sep = " > ")
    new_row$variable <- paste(node_label, "\nn = ", new_row$NumObs)
    new_row$rule <- node_label
    if(is.nan(new_row$SplitValue)) {
      n_objs <- round(new_row[,class_cols] * new_row$NumObs)
      classify <- paste((names(tree)[class_cols])[n_objs != 0], 
                        n_objs[n_objs != 0],
                        collapse = "\n")
      new_row$variable <- paste(new_row$variable, classify, sep = "\n")
    }
    new_row$group <- group
    tree[which(tree$Node == node),] <<- new_row
    if(!is.nan(new_row$SplitValue)){
      walk_tree(new_row$NextLeft, depth + 1, rightness - 2/(depth/2 + 1), 
                left_label, paste(group, "L"))
      walk_tree(new_row$NextRight, depth + 1, rightness + 2/(depth/2 + 1), 
                right_label, paste(group, "R"))
    }
  }
  
  walk_tree(0, 0, 0)
  tree$depth <- max(tree$depth) - tree$depth
  tree$type <- is.nan(tree$NextLeft)
  tree$group <- substr(tree$group, 1, nchar(tree$group) - 1)

  if(plot)
  {
  print(ggplot(tree, aes(rightness, depth)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = rightness, xend = rightness, 
                     y = depth, yend = depth - 1, alpha = type)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = group)) +
    geom_label(aes(label = variable, fill = type), size = 4) + 
    theme_void() + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 1)) + 
    suppressWarnings(scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0)))  +
    theme(legend.position = "none"))
  }
  tree$isLeaf <- is.nan(tree$NextLeft)
  tree[c(match(c("Node", "rule", "depth", "isLeaf"), names(tree)), class_cols)]
}
```

and this allows:

```r
df <- RLT_tree(fit, plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

and

```
df
#>    Node               rule depth isLeaf    setosa versicolor virginica
#> 1     0              Start     6  FALSE 0.3111111 0.34814815 0.3407407
#> 2     1  Sepal.Width < 3.2     5  FALSE 0.1573034 0.51685393 0.3258427
#> 3     2  Sepal.Width > 3.2     5  FALSE 0.6086957 0.02173913 0.3695652
#> 4     3 Sepal.Length < 5.4     4  FALSE 0.7000000 0.30000000 0.0000000
#> 5     4 Sepal.Length > 5.4     4   TRUE 0.0000000 0.57971014 0.4202899
#> 6     5 Petal.Length < 1.3     3   TRUE 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
#> 7     6 Petal.Length > 1.3     3  FALSE 0.6000000 0.40000000 0.0000000
#> 8     7 Petal.Length < 1.4     2   TRUE 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
#> 9     8 Petal.Length > 1.4     2  FALSE 0.5000000 0.50000000 0.0000000
#> 10    9 Petal.Length < 3.9     1  FALSE 0.7500000 0.25000000 0.0000000
#> 11   10 Petal.Length > 3.9     1   TRUE 0.0000000 1.00000000 0.0000000
#> 12   11 Sepal.Length < 4.9     0   TRUE 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
#> 13   12 Sepal.Length > 4.9     0   TRUE 0.0000000 1.00000000 0.0000000
#> 14   13  Petal.Width < 0.2     4   TRUE 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
#> 15   14  Petal.Width > 0.2     4  FALSE 0.3793103 0.03448276 0.5862069
#> 16   15 Sepal.Length < 5.7     3   TRUE 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
#> 17   16 Sepal.Length > 5.7     3  FALSE 0.0000000 0.05555556 0.9444444
#> 18   17  Sepal.Width < 3.3     2   TRUE 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
#> 19   18  Sepal.Width > 3.3     2  FALSE 0.0000000 0.08333333 0.9166667
#> 20   19 Petal.Length < 6.1     1  FALSE 0.0000000 0.11111111 0.8888889
#> 21   20 Petal.Length > 6.1     1   TRUE 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
#> 22   21 Sepal.Length < 6.3     0   TRUE 0.0000000 0.16666667 0.8333333
#> 23   22 Sepal.Length > 6.3     0   TRUE 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
```

To show this works in the more general case, we can also do:

```r
fit2 = RLT(mtcars[,1:3], factor(rownames(mtcars)), model = "classification", ntrees = 1)

df <- RLT_tree(fit2)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: Thank you so much for your answer! It looks wonderful! I will try to study the output of " fit$FittedTrees[[1]]" myself! (I am curious to see how you were able to figure out how to interpret the table). Do you think that the answer you provided will also work for regression examples? Thanks again!

Comment: @stats555 it _sort of_ works for regression models. It would probably need tweaked to include the `NodeMean` value for each node in the regression result though, and to have this displayed on the plot. I'm happy to have a go at this at some point if you get stuck.